# How to set the value in ajax select2

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

How can I set value in select2. I have tried many ways but I am not able to get it work.I am able to implement the ajax search in the select2. But when I am setting the data its not working.

Code:

```
$('#pin_code').select2({
    dropdownAutoWidth: true,
    placeholder: 'Select an option',
    width: 'resolve',
    delay: 250,
    minimumInputLength: 4,
    minimumResultsForSearch: 10,
    ajax: {
        url: "controller/postalCode.php",
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        data: function(params) {
            var queryParameters = {
                qry: params.term,
                config: "all_code",
            }
            return queryParameters;
        }
    }
});
```

I have tried as of now:

```
1. $("#pin_code").select2('data', { id:"Ab548", text: "Ab548"});
2. $("#pin_code").val("Ab548").change()
3. $("#pin_code").val("Ab548")
4. $("#pin_code").val("Ab548").trigger("change");
5. $("#pin_code").val("Ab548").select2('destroy').select2();
```

Nothing worked. I am using the select2 version: 4.1.0-rc

> https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js

Any suggestion will be of great help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to the [docs](https://select2.org/data-sources/ajax#default-pre-selected-values): To provide default selections, you may include an `<option>` for each selection that contains the value and text that should be displayed:

```
<select id="pin_code">
  <option value="Ab548" selected="selected">Ab548</option>
</select>
```

Or if you want to do it programmatically, you can find info [here](https://select2.org/programmatic-control/add-select-clear-items#preselecting-options-in-an-remotely-sourced-ajax-select2).